# How to display image in detail view using dataTransform?

Tags: xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am able to display image and other source in my index page using dataTransform. 
but i have problem of displaying the same source image in my detail view.
I post all my code and my error is 
[It doesn't display image but other attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOoyc.png)

```html
// index.xml

<Alloy>
 <Collection src="products"/>
  <Window class="container">
    <TableView filterAttribute="title"  dataCollection="products" id="productTableView" dataTransform="myTransformer">
      <SearchBar platform="android,ios"id="search" barColor="#000" showCancel="true" height="43" top="0" />
   <TableViewRow height="150dp" productId="{productid}">
        <View layout="vertical" top="10">
          <View height="150" layout="horizontal">
            <View backgroundColor="white" left="5dp" width="40%">
              // image here
              <ImageView image="{my_image}"></ImageView>
            </View>
            <View backgroundColor="white" layout="vertical" left="15dp" width="50%">
              <Label id="titel" text="{title}"></Label>
              <Label id="price" text="{price},{currency}"></Label>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TableViewRow>
    </TableView>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

```html
// productdetails.xml
<Alloy>
      <Window id="detailWindow" class="container" onClick="CloseWindow">
  <View layout="vertical" top="100dp">
   <ImageView image="{my_image}" width="96%"></ImageView>
   <Label id="titel" text="{title}"></Label>
            <Button id="closeBtn" title="Back"></Button>
  </View>
 </Window>
</Alloy>
```

```js
//index.js

Alloy.Collections.products.fetch();

function myTransformer(model) {
  var transform = model.toJSON();

  transform.my_image = transform.images[0].sizes['100'];

  return transform;
}


$.index.open();


var args = arguments[0] || {};
var collection = Alloy.Collections.products;
collection.fetch({ 
    success : function(){
        _.each(collection.models, function(element, index, list){
    element.attributes.productid = element.cid;
           
 });
    },
    error : function(){
        Ti.API.error("hmm - this is not good!");
    }
});

$.productTableView.addEventListener('click', function(_event) {
 // get the correct model
 var model =
     Alloy.Collections.products.getByCid(_event.rowData.productId);
 model.__transform = {};
 // create the controller and pass in the model
 var detailController = Alloy.createController('productdetails', {
     $model : model
 });
    // get view returns the root view when no view ID is provided
    detailController.getView().open({
        model : true
    });
});
```

```js
//productdetails.js


var args = arguments[0] || {};



// close the window when button is clicked
$.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
   CloseWindow();
});

function CloseWindow()
{
  $.detailWindow.close();
}

// Free model-view data binding resources when this
// view-controller closes
$.detailWindow.addEventListener('close', function() {
    $.destroy();
});
```

Comment: set a width and height on the image? What is the problem you have!

Comment: I have a problem on the Detailview page Couldn't display the image ? <ImageView image="{$.Product.my_image}" width="99%" height="40%"></ImageView>

Comment: When you create the detailController, you pass the specific Product via the data attribute. var detailController = Alloy.createController('productdetails', {
        data : model
    }); Why do you set the property dataCollection on your ScrollView? Wouldn't it be solved if you just bind to <ImageView image="{my_image}"? instead of {$.Product.my_image} ?

Comment: I removed the property datacollection and use now only {my_image} but there is still error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use data binding on the detail page the trick is to pass the model as `$model`. In the detail view simply use `{attributeName}`. I believe Alloy does expect `$model.__transform` to exist. So before you pass it be sure to add that (simply an empty object).

```
// get the correct model
var model =
    Alloy.Collections.products.getByCid(_event.rowData.productId);
model.__transform = {};
// create the controller and pass in the model
var detailController = Alloy.createController('productdetails', {
    $model : model
});
```

Comment: Which error do you get? If you have passed your model during controller creation (see Fokke Zandbergen's comment), then your detailView's controller already knows the model. You don't have to set model="$.model" on the <Window>. Assuming you created the controller as Fokke Zandbergen explained, your detailview should only contain <Alloy><Window id="detailWindow" class="container" onClick="CloseWindow"><ImageView image="{my_image}" width="96%"></ImageView> .. (thus no <Model> tag nor a model attribute on <Window>

Comment: Hej Fokke, Can it be something wrong with my Models ?

Comment: Is your latest code available? Or can you update your original question so that it reflects your latest code changes.

Comment: Get rid of "$.Product.set(args.data.attributes);" and the "<Model>" tag in the view for the detail page. That should do it.

Comment: Hej Fokke I get rid of  "$.Product.set(args.data.attributes);" and the Model tag too... now it doesn't show error but it is empty i can display other attribute not image. Hej DavidCyp i updated the question with the updated code.

Comment: O, that's because that comes from your transformer. So change 'model.__transform = {};' to 'model.__transform = myTransformer(model);'

Comment: Jep...that was it it works now. Thankyou so much Fokke. you are very helpful.